# Sessions, verification, and manipulation outside request

Tags: node.js, mongodb, session, redis

My app loads the user's document from the database into a redis session upon login. It then does nearly all verification of requests against the session object.

`The problem`: Modify ongoing sessions outside of the request/response cycle to update verification information.

For example, if the user is subscribed to a blog posts category and they can read posts in that category as well as contribute to that category. But if the moderator of that category decides to delete it then I need to remove that category not only from the user documents in the database on disk but also the user sessions in redis.

As far as I know, the only way I could do this is by saving a reference to the session id in the user's document in the database and lookup the corresponding session in redis.

The issue is that I'm not sure if the sessions are designed to be modified outside of the request/response cycle because I haven't really seen any related topics of people wanting to do this when I do a google search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think storing info about session on mongo is a good idea. What happens if a user is logged in from two devices at the same time? I guess you will have two session object in that case (otherwise, there should be a mechanism for guessing the session given a user, and then you wouldn't have your current problem).

My suggestion would be storing in redis the SET of sessions started by a user. When the user logs in, you add the new session id to a SET with the user id as part of the key. When a user logs out, you remove the corresponding entry from the SET.

Of course you have the problem of sessions expiring out without the user manually logging out (in case you have that behavviour). For that you can just SETEXP to the user set everytime a new session is started. As long as your SETEXP time is a bit longer than your session expiration time, you are sure the sessions will be stored in your SET for as long as your sessions exists.

The new version of redis will have a Observe commands, that would make it easier to remove sessions that get deleted from your set object. You would only need to observe the creation/deletion of session objects and you could manage your SET insert/deletions according to that. Until that command is official, you will have to stick with expiring by time.

Comment: So, modifying user sessions outside of that user's request won't cause unforeseen problems?

Comment: when done on the server-side, a user session is just a collection of fields, and then a mechanism to identify that session, usually via a cookie containing the session id. As long as you don't change the session key or remove any fields the rest of the application relies on, you shouldn't have any problems changing values of the session.

Comment: I was thinking about forming a app-side, foreign-key relationship between all sessions a particular user has going and a single redis key/value which stores the user's session object and whose expiry is updated any time it is accessed to the same ttl as the session key/value (1 day). So it would be: `sess1: 123, sess2: 123, sess3: 123, user:123: { user json object }`. On the app side I would query for `user + ':' + _id (borrowed from user's mongo _id) which I would then setex update the ttl along with any changes. Would this be a good idea in your opinion?

Comment: It sounds like a good plan. Depending on how you want to manage the session info, you might prefer to use a Redis hash rather than storing the object as a JSON. That way you would be able to set/get individual session values directly from Redis and you would save yourself the trouble of serializing/deserializing your json everytime you want to write or read from it